# Help with Bathroom Light installation

Tags: light-fixture, bathroom-fixtures

I am having some trouble figuring out how to reinstall this light fixture in my bathroom. My wife unscrewed it to paint behind on the wall, but I do not see how I am supposed to get the thing back on the mount!

Seems straight forward. Three screws go through the bulb housing and through a small metal piece and nut connecting it to the mount on the wall... however, the nuts are not secure in the position under the metal piece and slip down to where I can not get the screw to thread through.

I feel like the best way to reconnect is to pull the entire mount off the wall and lay it flat on the table, but if one nut slips while trying to place the screws into position I have to pull it all apart and start over.

Is there something I am missing or some trick to make this faster/easier?

Thank you for any advice!

[image: Front]
[image: Back]

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. There's no way that screw was meant to be undone by the consumer. I'm thinking you need to take the unit off the wall, reassemble, and then re-mount it.

Comment: @DanielGriscom - I was afraid of that... thanks for the response!

Comment: Are you sure a screw goes into the bulb socket? That seems really "odd" to me. The potential for electrifying the fixture seems pretty good....  Good enough that I'd consider a new fixture just for peace of mind.

Comment: That is where my wife said she unscrewed them from and the bulb sockets are loose without them so... I was hoping to avoid disconnecting all the wiring, to try and piece it back together, but I don't think I have much choice... If i can't get it I will likely just buy a new one...